# Typescript: AngularJS 1 constant issue

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am creating an app with TypeScript and AngularJS 1, and I have run into a problem with creating a constant and passing the constant to the other class. I  have the following constant in my app:

```
module app{
       export class AUTH_EVENTS {
            static get Default():any {
                    return {
                    LOGIN_SUCCESS: 'AUTH_EVENTS:LOGIN_SUCCESS',
                    LOGIN_FAILED: 'AUTH_EVENTS:LOGIN_FAILED',
                    LOGOUT_SUCCESS: 'AUTH_EVENTS:LOGOUT_SUCCESS',
                    LOGOUT_FAILED: 'AUTH_EVENTS:LOGOUT_FAILED',
                    SESSION_TIMEOUT: 'AUTH_EVENTS:SESSION_TIMEOUT',
                    NOT_AUTHORIZED: 'AUTH_EVENTS:NOT_AUTHORIZED'
                };
            }
        }
 var app = getModule();
 app.constant("AUTH_EVENTS", AUTH_EVENTS.Default())
}
```

Which I try to access here:

```
module app{
    class auth{

        constructor(public $q: ng.IQService,
            public $state:angular.ui.IState, 
            public AUTH_EVENTS: AUTH_EVENTS){
        }

             responseError(response:any) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    console.log(this.AUTH_EVENTS.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
                } 
                return this.$q.reject(response);
        }


    }
}
```

The issue that I have, is that in

```
console.log(this.AUTH_EVENTS.LOGIN_SUCCESS)
```

the LOGIN_SUCCESS is not defined.

Do you have any ideas why is this happening? Is there any issue with defining the constant, or is it the issue with the class auth. To be more specific, this is the error that I get when I compile TS into JS:

```
error TS2339: Property 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' does not exist on type 'AUTH_EVENTS'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this definiton:

```
module app{ 
   export class AUTH_EVENTS {       
       LOGIN_SUCCESS= 'AUTH_EVENTS:LOGIN_SUCCESS';
       LOGIN_FAILED= 'AUTH_EVENTS:LOGIN_FAILED';
       LOGOUT_SUCCESS= 'AUTH_EVENTS:LOGOUT_SUCCESS';
       LOGOUT_FAILED= 'AUTH_EVENTS:LOGOUT_FAILED';
       SESSION_TIMEOUT= 'AUTH_EVENTS:SESSION_TIMEOUT';
       NOT_AUTHORIZED= 'AUTH_EVENTS:NOT_AUTHORIZED';
       static  Default() { return new AUTH_EVENTS(); }
    }
  var app = getModule();
  app.constant("AUTH_EVENTS", AUTH_EVENTS.Default())
}
```

Comment: It works well. I managed to fix with by deleting the static Default, and set all the variables within the export class AUTH_EVENTS to public. Could you tell me if there are any benefits of setting the static Default over setting the variables to public?

Comment: I would say, that it depends on your preferences only. I do prefer public members of class, because it is easy to use as a type (that class).... ALSO, public is default access modifier if its value is omitted...

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I thought :)